# Динамический пересчет результата вычисления в формуле excel (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, excel-формулы

Есть excel файл, допустим, нужно внести изменения в соответствующую ячейку, и пересчитать формулу, всё хорошо работает в приложенном примере, если формула содержит в себе лишь ячейки с числами, но может содержать и другие формулы, а они в свою очередь другие, и т.д.

У меня идея примерно такая: отфильтровываем все формулы в файле, вычисляем содержит ли формула другие формулы, рекурсивно пересчитываем все эти формулы, внося изменения в WorkSheet в итоге финальная формула содержит уже результат пересчета с учётом изменений в зависимых формулах.

Вопрос собственно, подходит ли данный подход для реализации задачи, описанной в первом абзаце, или есть способ проще/изящнее?

В примере использованы: 
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs, https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser

```js
const stringifyResultOfReadingFile = '{"!margins":{"left":0.75,"right":0.75,"top":1,"bottom":1,"header":0.5,"footer":0.5},"B1":{"v":10,"t":"n","w":"10"},"C1":{"v":40,"t":"n","w":"40"},"B2":{"v":20,"t":"n","w":"20"},"C2":{"v":50,"t":"n","w":"50"},"B3":{"v":30,"t":"n","w":"30"},"C3":{"v":60,"t":"n","w":"60"},"B4":{"v":6000,"t":"n","f":"PRODUCT(B1:B3)","w":"6000"},"C4":{"v":150,"t":"n","f":"SUM($C1:$C3)","w":"150"},"D4":{"v":150,"t":"n","f":"SUM($C1:$C3)","w":"150"},"E4":{"v":150,"t":"n","f":"SUM($C1:$C3)","w":"150"},"B6":{"v":6150,"t":"n","f":"SUM(B4,C4)","w":"6150"},"!ref":"A1:P29","!merges":[{"s":{"c":5,"r":12},"e":{"c":7,"r":14}},{"s":{"c":5,"r":17},"e":{"c":7,"r":19}},{"s":{"c":5,"r":20},"e":{"c":6,"r":20}},{"s":{"c":8,"r":17},"e":{"c":8,"r":20}},{"s":{"c":1,"r":5},"e":{"c":2,"r":5}}]}';

class XlsDoc {
  constructor(path) {
    this.pathFile = path;
  }
  formulasRange(dataArr) {
    const parser = new formulaParser.Parser();
    parser.on('callRangeValue', (startCellCoord, endCellCoord, done) => {
      dataArr;
      let fragment = [];
      for (
        let row = startCellCoord.row.index; row <= endCellCoord.row.index; row++
      ) {
        const rowData = dataArr[row];
        let colFragment = [];
        for (
          let col = startCellCoord.column.index; col <= endCellCoord.column.index; col++
        ) {
          colFragment.push(rowData[col]);
        }
        fragment.push(colFragment);
      }
      if (fragment) {
        done(fragment);
      }
    });
    return parser;
  }
  simpleFormula(data) {
    const parser = new formulaParser.Parser();
    parser.on('callCellValue', function(cellCoord, done) {
      // using label
      const getValue = data.get(cellCoord.label);
      if (getValue) {
        done(getValue.v);
      }
    });
    return parser;
  }
  calculateFormula() {
    const workBook = JSON.parse(this.pathFile);
    workBook['C2'].v = 10;
    const mapSheet = new Map(Object.entries(workBook));
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workBook, {
      header: 1,
    });
    const parser = workBook['B6'].f.includes(':') ?
      this.formulasRange(data) :
      this.simpleFormula(mapSheet);
    return parser.parse(workBook['B6'].f);
  }
}

const exmple = new XlsDoc(stringifyResultOfReadingFile);
console.log(exmple.calculateFormula());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hot-formula-parser@3.0.2/dist/formula-parser.min.js"></script>
```